# REMAP_DATA functionality from DBMS_DATAPUMP

Tags: oracle, datapump

I'm trying to create a datapump export from the API (DBMS_DATAPUMP) with Oracle 11.2.

If I use the command line then I can specify REMAP_DATA clauses in the parameter file, meaning the data in particular columns is passed through a function, e.g.:

```
remap_data=MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.PASSWORD:obs.remap_pkg.raw_to_null
```

However, I can't find an API call to achieve this.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_datpmp.htm

Does anybody know if such an API exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found DATA_REMAP

This procedure specifies transformations to be applied to column data as it is exported from, or imported into, a database.

Syntax

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.DATA_REMAP(
   handle          IN NUMBER,
   name            IN VARCHAR2,
   table_name      IN VARCHAR2,
   column          IN VARCHAR2,
   remap_function  IN VARCHAR2),
   schema          IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

The given in reference parameter name '**remap_function**' doesn't work.
Try '**function**' instead.

And parameter values (e.g. table, column and function names) must be in upper case.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_datpmp.htm#BABCJGAB

Comment: this. Still not fixed on the documentation page. Cost me one hour to find this.